# DateParsing a string converted from a Date

Tags: c#, date-parsing

I have a datetime value that I want displaying as a string in particular format, at the moment I am trying this

```
 lastUpdate = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpDt.ToString(), "d/M/YYYY",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

The error i'm getting is `FormatException`

Comment: Then it's an incorrect format. Since you haven't posted the string you send into it, it's impossible for us to determine why. Also, why are you calling `.ToString()` on `tmpDt`? What type is `tmpDt`?

Comment: FormatException means your date was in the wrong format. Please show your date format in `tmpDt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the FormatException because you use a DateTime.ToString() and then expect it to be in " d/M/YYYY"  for parsing it.

If you want to display your DateTime in a certain format you should use the overloads for DateTime.ToString().

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
tmpDt.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myDateTimeObj.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use ToString() with a format specifier

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";   
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```